# How do I apply a list of arguments to a block in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, apply

Does Objective C have a function like Smalltalk's `Block valueWithArguments`?

I'm looking for a function with a signature like:

```
apply(^(), NSArray* args)
```

Alternatively, is there a way to call a selector over a list of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With blocks you probably have to do some `va_args` magic. Calling a selector with variable arguments can be done but you probably want some helpers to make it a bit less painful.

NSObject+performSelectorWithArgsArray.h

```
@interface NSObject (performSelectorWithArgsArray)
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)sel withArgsArray:(NSArray *)args;
@end
```

NSObject+performSelectorWithArgsArray.m

```
@implementation NSObject (performSelectorWithArgsArray)
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)sel withArgsArray:(NSArray *)args {
  NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                       [self methodSignatureForSelector:sel]];
  [inv setSelector:sel];
  [inv setTarget:self];
  for (int i = 0; i < args.count; i++) {
    id a = [args objectAtIndex:i];
    [inv setArgument:&a atIndex:2 + i]; // 0 is target, 1 is cmd-selector
  }
  [inv invoke];

  NSNumber *r;
  [inv getReturnValue:&r];
  return r;
}
@end
```

And then use it like this:

```
#import "NSObject+performSelectorWithArgs.h"

@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (NSNumber *)withA:(NSNumber *)a withB:(NSNumber *)b {
  return [NSNumber numberWithInt:a.intValue + b.intValue];
}
@end

- (void)someMethod {
  SomeClass *a = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
  SEL sel = @selector(withA:withB:);
  NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                   nil];
  NSNumber *r = [a performSelector:sel withArgsArray:args];
  NSLog(@"%d", r.intValue);
}
```

If you choose to do something like this I recommend that you really read up on how `NSInvocation` works as it can bite quite hard. Not sure if it is possible to do this without requiring that all arguments and return value are objects.

Comment: Are selectors bundled with their objects/classes? If not, could you rewrite your example to include an object/class argument?

Comment: You mean like this? I don't think the selectors depend on classes in anyway, you can send any selector in a message to an instance and hope that it deals with it. But one thing i don't really understand it show the return type is handled, seams to always be a `void *` when using `NSInvocation`.

Comment: But you can use the `void *` return value to return a object reference.

Comment: `void*` is the trick I use in [qc](https://github.com/mcandre/qc). I'd like to avoid it, because the result is you still need to explicitly cast the returned values, and you end up with nearly the same thing in [objcheck](https://github.com/mcandre/objcheck).

Comment: Just realized that i got a bit carried away and overengineered it quite a bit and not used an array at all. Updated my answer to actually use an array of argument and also remove the `withA:withB` from the `SomeClass` interface to show that it does not need to be a public method.

Comment: Good work, that. Would you consider forking my [GitHub](https://github.com/mcandre/objcheck) code? I think you'll see why a reference to the class/object must be passed as well.

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` has the methods `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` and `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` is that what you are looking for?

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil]
 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  NSLog(@"%d: %@", idx, obj);
}];
```

Comment: Not quite. From the docs: "The block takes three arguments." The function I'm after wouldn't require blocks to use the special tertiary-variable syntax.

Comment: Ah now i see, posted a new answer.